# Add custom property in userinfo endpoint in Identity Server 4

Tags: identityserver4

I have an Identity Server 4 solution. All of the client apps requesting login, requires to know the Orgs assigned to a user. For instance, a user can have 2 restaurants & 2 supplier orgs assigned to it. Can I add this info to a property called "Orgs" with the array value on userinfo endpoint in Identity Server 4?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add as many customs properties/claims in token. So basically IdS4 provided this `connect/userinfo` endpoint to fetch user-specific additional properties and you can extend this behavior by implementing [IProfileService](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html) interface. So whenever the client requests the new token or hits userinfo endpoint additional properties it will hit this extended helper class and you will be able to add custom properties/claims here.

Sample code: This is really minimal code that will fulfill your requirement, but there are more dependencies that you can inject into the constructor.

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
  public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
  {
     context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("YourCustomClaimType", "YourCustomClaimValue"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any reference I can follow to add new property?

Comment: Let me update my original ans with sample code

Comment: @Jay I have updated my answer with minimal sample code, take a look.

Comment: I was aware of this particular method, which accept string value. But I want to add an array value. (multiple orgs code per user)

Comment: You can put any value in it, you just need to process the object and convert that object into a string. It's up to you how you want to process and store it.